# Python: want to split the last bracket of item in list only

Tags: python, split

I have 20000 items in the list, and want a robust and fast way to split only the last bracket () in the list. Some items has two brackets, I want the first bracket remains. here is my current code.

```
output = ['ADLN (ADLN.SI)',
 'CN ACCESS INDEX (TR) (SGXCN2.SI)',
 'CN ACCESS STB (10%) INDEX (SGXCN7.SI)',
 'CN ACCESS STB (5%) INDEX (SGXCN6.SI)',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC (1X) TR IDX (SGXCN15.SI)',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC INV 1X TR KRW IDX (SGXCN13.SI)',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC LEV 2X TR IDX (SGXCN14.SI)',
 'FTSE ST All-Share Index (FSTAS.SI)',
 'FTSE ST Basic Materials Index (FSTAS1000.SI)',
 'FTSE ST Catalist Index (FSTICA.SI)']
mylist =[]
for x in range len(output):
    a = ouput[x].split(')')
    b = a[0].split('('))
    mylist.append(b[0])
    mylist.append(b[1])
```

I able to split only if it is only one bracket. If two brackets, it will not work.
The  output I want is as below:

```
'ADLN' ,'ADLN.SI',
 'CN ACCESS INDEX (TR)', 'SGXCN2.SI',
 'CN ACCESS STB (10%) INDEX ','SGXCN7.SI',
 'CN ACCESS STB (5%) INDEX ','SGXCN6.SI',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC (1X) TR IDX ','SGXCN15.SI',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC INV 1X TR KRW IDX','SGXCN13.SI',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC LEV 2X TR IDX','SGXCN14.SI',
 'FTSE ST All-Share Index','FSTAS.SI',
 'FTSE ST Basic Materials Index','FSTAS1000.SI',
 'FTSE ST Catalist Index',FSTICA.SI'
```

using loop will need some time, if there any better way?

Comment: Hi Vindex...have you tried the rsplit? That means right split --> starting from the last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using `str.rpartition`. It splits into a 3-item list: left, separator, and right. And starts from right so last opening parenthesis is considered. Append left & right (minus the last parenthesis) to your list.

```
mylist=[]
for i in output:
    parts = i.rpartition("(")
    mylist.append(parts[0])
    mylist.append(parts[2][:-1])

print(mylist)
```

result:

```
['ADLN ', 'ADLN.SI', 'CN ACCESS INDEX (TR) ', 'SGXCN2.SI', 'CN ACCESS STB (10%) INDEX ', 'SGXCN7.SI', 'CN ACCESS STB (5%) INDEX ', 'SGXCN6.SI', 'FNGUIDE CN ACC (1X) TR IDX ', 'SGXCN15.SI', 'FNGUIDE CN ACC INV 1X TR KRW IDX ', 'SGXCN13.SI', 'FNGUIDE CN ACC LEV 2X TR IDX ', 'SGXCN14.SI', 'FTSE ST All-Share Index ', 'FSTAS.SI', 'FTSE ST Basic Materials Index ', 'FSTAS1000.SI', 'FTSE ST Catalist Index ', 'FSTICA.SI']
```

doing it in a list comprehension sounds a tad tougher but doable to, using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
import itertools

mylist=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((i.rpartition("(")[0],i.rpartition("(")[2][:-1]) for i in output))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement with generators like so:

```
output = ['ADLN (ADLN.SI)',
 'CN ACCESS INDEX (TR) (SGXCN2.SI)',
 'CN ACCESS STB (10%) INDEX (SGXCN7.SI)',
 'CN ACCESS STB (5%) INDEX (SGXCN6.SI)',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC (1X) TR IDX (SGXCN15.SI)',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC INV 1X TR KRW IDX (SGXCN13.SI)',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC LEV 2X TR IDX (SGXCN14.SI)',
 'FTSE ST All-Share Index (FSTAS.SI)',
 'FTSE ST Basic Materials Index (FSTAS1000.SI)',
 'FTSE ST Catalist Index (FSTICA.SI)']

out2 = (b.strip('()') if b.startswith('(') else b for a in (a.rsplit(' ', 1) for a in output) for b in a)
list(out2)
```

Output:

```
['ADLN',
 'ADLN.SI',
 'CN ACCESS INDEX (TR)',
 'SGXCN2.SI',
 'CN ACCESS STB (10%) INDEX',
 'SGXCN7.SI',
 'CN ACCESS STB (5%) INDEX',
 'SGXCN6.SI',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC (1X) TR IDX',
 'SGXCN15.SI',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC INV 1X TR KRW IDX',
 'SGXCN13.SI',
 'FNGUIDE CN ACC LEV 2X TR IDX',
 'SGXCN14.SI',
 'FTSE ST All-Share Index',
 'FSTAS.SI',
 'FTSE ST Basic Materials Index',
 'FSTAS1000.SI',
 'FTSE ST Catalist Index',
 'FSTICA.SI']
```

Answer (score 1):

use `rsplit()`:

```
str.rsplit(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
```

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter
>   string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done, the
>   rightmost ones. If sep is not specified or None, any whitespace string
>   is a separator.

this `rsplit` go through from right to left and you can use `maxsplit` to tell it to stop at first delimiter.

```
for text in output:
    i, j = text.rsplit(' ', 1)
    print(i, j.strip('()'))
```

out:

```
ADLN ADLN.SI
CN ACCESS INDEX (TR) SGXCN2.SI
CN ACCESS STB (10%) INDEX SGXCN7.SI
CN ACCESS STB (5%) INDEX SGXCN6.SI
FNGUIDE CN ACC (1X) TR IDX SGXCN15.SI
FNGUIDE CN ACC INV 1X TR KRW IDX SGXCN13.SI
FNGUIDE CN ACC LEV 2X TR IDX SGXCN14.SI
FTSE ST All-Share Index FSTAS.SI
FTSE ST Basic Materials Index FSTAS1000.SI
FTSE ST Catalist Index FSTICA.SI
```

Comment: `CN ACCESS INDEX (TR`. Row 3 is undesired. Its stripping out the right bracket.

Comment: @MYGz the two part is `i` and `j`, I print it out, the OP can use it if he need those.

Comment: Aight. My bad. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before I would use the rsplit with value=1 --> it means only the last occurrence as you asked. Pleas check my code below.

```
mylist =[]
for x in range(len(output)):
    a = output[x].rsplit(')',1)
    b = a[0].rsplit('(',1)
    mylist.append(b[0])
    mylist.append(b[1])
print mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

This results in the answer you want, also ensures there aren't trailing spaces and such.

```
def split_string(a):
    p = a.rpartition('(')
    out1 = p[0].strip()
    out2 = p[2].partition(')')[0]
    return [out1, out2]

results = []
for i in output:
    res = split_string(i)
    results.extend(res)
```

Output:

```
['ADLN', 'ADLN.SI', 'CN ACCESS INDEX (TR)', 'SGXCN2.SI', 'CN ACCESS STB (10%) INDEX', 'SGXCN7.SI', 'CN ACCESS STB (5%) INDEX', 'SGXCN6.SI', 'FNGUIDE CN ACC (1X) TR IDX', 'SGXCN15.SI', 'FNGUIDE CN ACC INV 1X TR KRW IDX', 'SGXCN13.SI', 'FNGUIDE CN ACC LEV 2X TR IDX', 'SGXCN14.SI', 'FTSE ST All-Share Index', 'FSTAS.SI', 'FTSE ST Basic Materials Index', 'FSTAS1000.SI', 'FTSE ST Catalist Index', 'FSTICA.SI']
```